# Why did all my folder dates suddenly change?

Tags: date, delphi, ide, directory, delphi-10-seattle

This morning I started the Delphi Seattle (Update 1) IDE into a project group 'X' I was working on yesterday (automatically, autosave options are on). I then immediately switched to another project group 'Y', I was (of course) not asked if I wanted to save changes.

Now the folder dates of all the projects in group X have changed to that time (9:25, Total Commander screenshot):

[image]

I just confirmed this behaviour by switching back and forth again.

Note that not *all* dates change. When there is no project in one of these folders, the date remains unchanged. But when a project resides in a *subfolder* (in this example `ClientDataset\NestedClientDatasets`), *that* subfolder date changes too.

What is going on here? Is this a bug?
I consider it unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder modified date that is reported is, as I understand it, the latest modified date of the objects in that folder. So look inside one of those folders to find out which file or files have that modified date. That will indicate which aspect of the IDE is responsible. Whether or not you can change the behaviour remains to be seen and will depend on which file it is that has been changed.

Personally I would not be surprised if the history tracking (the __history folders) was responsible. If that is the case then you can disable history tracking for instance by using Andy Hausladen's tools.

Comment: The .identcache files have all changed (Temporary cache files created by refactoring engine to improve performance)

Comment: Ok, that's the key information. I guess the next steps are clear. You need to either accept this behaviour or find a way to stop the IDE generating these files. Personally I would just ignore folder modified dates and move on. Why do you feel it important to look at these dates? I use my revision control software to inform me of any modifications to my source. I think that is far more robust.

Comment: It is not *that* important, it's just that an overview of the folders now no longer shows me which ones are recent/older projects.

Comment: @david:.AFAIK, history tracking can be turned off in the IDE anyway.